# USB Headset: Device descriptor request failed (error 43)

Tags: windows-10, usb, audio, drivers

[image]

The headset I'm trying to connect is Exibel GHX-5 which I found no driver for.
I already tried uninstall/install its driver and power recycling the PC.

I had the same issue when trying this headset on a laptop.

I suspect Windows 10 isn't handling the headset well (both test PC's were W10).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defective product. Got a working replacement.
EDIT: decided it was defect after trying 3 different PC's and getting same error.

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  Anything you can add to help others in a similar situation, like how you diagnosed the problem?

Answer (score 2):

If the "GET_DESCRIPTOR" command failed, the device has a very serious problem. This command is the first one executed by host driver after USB port reset. This error means that the device DID SIGNAL the connect event (port status shows as "connected"), but the very first control function has failed, at least after three reset attempts, and three attempts to GET_DESCRIPTOR after each USB reset.

One fairly frequent cause of this malfunction is when a device outputs some transient garbage on data lines during its power-up, so the port logic fails to detects the port speed correctly. In this case the controller begins the communication with device at WRONG speed rate, and the device fails to respond for obvious reasons.

Most frequent case is when a poorly-designed FS or HS device has a glitch on D- line on power startup, and the host believes that it should talk to a LS device.

The less frequent case is [when a HS device handshake fails](https://superuser.com/a/1130446/620011) on one or another end of USB link, so either a communication goes at HS into a device didn't switch into HS mode, or the device is in HS mode, but port status gets screwed, and host tries FS signals into HS-terminated bus.